# C++ Constructor and Destructor of class having queue as member

Tags: c++

I have a header file that I must respect to implement my class, it has this:

```
class Example {
private:

    std::queue<ObjectOfClass> Elements;

public:
        Example ();
        ~Example ();

};
```

I tried to write into the .cpp file this code, but I'm not sure if it's good:

```
// Constructor
Example::Example() {
    std::queue<ObjectOfClass> Elements;  //maybe I should leave it all empty? not sure
}

// Destructor
Example::~Example() {
    while (!Elements.empty())
    {
        Elements.pop();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a bad header. You shouldn't need a destructor here.

Comment: What the constructor and destructor body should look like depends on what the class is supposed to do. In any case you most likely don't need the destructor at all. So leave it empty if you must have it declared. `std::queue<ObjectOfClass> Elements;` in the constructor is not actually doing anything anyway, so you can remove that as well.

Comment: @uneven_mark will leaving it empty create a memory leak though, or are non-pointer data members destroyed even if you don't delete them in the destructor?

Comment: @Chipster Each member's destructor is run after the class destructor, so there is no problem.

Comment: I think that using destructor is for teaching purpose, not sure if leaving both empty will nicely seen, but thank you anyway.

Comment: @StayAlone **Not** leaving the destructor empty would be plain wrong. What you have written in at the moment is completely redundant and will only significantly slow down the program. And the default constructor should probably look like `Example::Example() : Elements() {}` at most if there are no other requirements and you want a clean implementation.

Comment: Is your approach malfunctioning? If it is, please describe the problem you have. If not, this might be more appropriate for [codereview.se] than for Stack Overflow. Or maybe the question could be improved (for SO) if you explained why you're not sure if the code is good? What looks wrong to you?

Comment: [Handy reading](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). What everyone is talking about is the Rule of Zero.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of errors in your .cpp file:

- you're defining a *local* queue of Elements in the body of the constructor, which will be destroyed when it completes; member variables like Elements should be initialised in the initialiser list for best performance
- popping each element individually in the destructor is unnecessary since stl containers will destroy the objects contained within them when they are destroyed

Since your constructor and destructor aren't really doing anything you don't even have to define them at all. The compiler will generate the default constructor and destructor for you implicitly. The class `std::queue` has its own default constructor, which will be called when an element of Example is created.

If you want to be a bit more explicit you could use the keyword `default` that came with C++11 for special class member functions like constructors and destructors in the header file itself, as well as having an initialiser list that initialises the member variable Elements:

```
Example(): Elements() {}
~Example() = default;
```

You can use defaulted and deleted functions to achieve your design goals.

Answer (score 2):

The code in both your constructor and destructor are not needed. To understand why you need to have a better understanding of object lifetime.

```
class Example {
    std::queue<ObjectOfClass> Elements;
}
```

In the above example each instance of your class will have a private member Elements of type std::queue. This class has a no argument constructor so you're not forced to initialize in your constructor, the default constructor is called for you. When `Elements` is destroyed the same is true for its members. Since `std::queue` is not a reference type its lifetime is tied to your `Example` instance.

However, lets assume that `std::queue<>` did not provide a no-argument constructor. In that case, you would need to initialize this member in your constructor. Since we are using C++ and care about performance we would initialize it like.

```
Example::Example() : Elements{someArgument} {

}
```

Comment: *" because we created this variable on the stack."* It doesn't matter whether the instance of `Example` (and `Elements` within it) was created on the stack or dynamically. In any case, destructors of members are called automatically when `Example` is destroyed.

Comment: @uneven_mark that is not true. If you have a dynamically allocated object the destructor is not called. That is just 100% wrong. If you call `new` then you need to call `delete` unless you have it wrapped in `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: What I mean is that `delete pointer_to_Example` will also call the member's destructors. Your current wording makes it sound as if that was only the case if `Example` is an automatic variable.

Comment: @freddy: no, he's right. He talks about members. Destructors of members are called automatically. What you describe - a dynamically allocated object - cannot be a member.

Comment: @MSalters I have never heard of a pointer not being a member of a class. Can you reference the documentation. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class says nothing about a pointer on a class not being a member.

Comment: @Freddy You did not actually resolve the confusion. The problem is that you say "*`std::queue` was created on the stack*". `Elements` is a member of `Example`. Whether a given instance of it is on the stack or heap (or technically has automatic or dynamic storage duration) depends on how the `Example` object is created, not how `Elements` is defined inside `Example`. The same is true for a pointer member. Where the pointer points does not say anything about its storage duration.

Comment: @freddy: a (dumb) pointer to a dynamically allocated object is not the object itself. The pointer doesn't have a destructor. Therefore, a member of pointer type is  ignored by the destructor of the containing class. You need to call `delete` or `delete[]` or `free` or whatever else is appropriate

Comment: @MSalters You're changing your statement here. No one is stating that a pointer is an object. By definition its a reference type that points to an object. You stated that a pointer is not a member and I simply asked you to provide reference since the cpp documentation stats that a (dump) pointers is considered a member.

Comment: @uneven_mark I removed stack and used reference/value type instead. good catch.

Comment: @freddy: actually, most pointers ARE objects, just of built-in type. Therefore they don't have destructors, just like `int` doesn't. Also I explicitly stated that pointers CAN be members. Not changing anything there.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this, it's clear for me now!